# Kick off Gerrit validation at ad-hoc time

Tags: gerrit

With our Gerrit setup, at times we need to kick off the Gerrit validation after non-Gerrit actions take place (internal jobs finish).

These internal jobs are out of our control, so we can't integrate them directly into our CI system.

We get stuck in a chicken-and-egg situation because we need the Gerrit validation to kick-off at an ad-hoc time but have no way of doing so and remain blocked from merging to master.

As a workaround, I was thinking there would be a way to push something like an empty patch-set, but simply changing the sha of HEAD and pushing doesn't seem to be working as I get:

```
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/drafts/master (no changes made)
```

Another idea is to make a trivial change to the commit message but that doesn't seem like an ideal solution.

Is there a best-practice for kicking off the Gerrit validation at an ad-hoc time? Perhaps a way to push an empty patch-set?

Comment: What do you mean with "Gerrit validation"?

Comment: I mean when the review labels that are configured on the Gerrit server are validated...the ones that automate certain +1 and -1's (besides the manual code review +1 and -1's). For example, we have custom labels that verify if the commit message has the correct format, if it doesn't, that particular label is given a -1 preventing merging into master until it is fixed. https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html